# Docker committed image doesn't retain the changes I make

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile, teamcity

I am using Teamcity server to hopefully do continuous integration. So I want to be able to have different images of servers that has the build steps and other data save inside the container, NOT stored locally on a machine volume.

I make the changes in the UI and perform a docker exec on the container and I see the configs and all the other new files there.

However, when I do a docker commit of that container and then run that new image, the files aren't there and the server runs as if it was a clean start.

How can I get it to have an image of persistent state of the server?

Comment: Usually you write a Dockerfile to build images.  The `docker exec`/`docker commit` path you describe here tends to not lead to reproducible images, and it’s hard for developers to do exactly what the build system is doing.

Comment: There are also corner cases around Docker volumes that could cause the effect you’re seeing.  “Images of servers” doesn’t sound like a normal Docker setup; if that’s your goal I might aim for a virtual machine setup with tooling like Ansible and Packer for an automated build sequence.

Comment: @DavidMaze How could I build images of it with a Dockerfile